# Laravel validation rule `confirmed` message show on wrong field

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

For example you have 2 inputs: `password` and `password_confirmed`.

**model**

```
$rule = array (
  'password' => 'min:4|confirmed',
  'password_confirmed'   => 'min:4',
);
```

If the user inputs the wrong password in the password_confirmed input, the validator sends the message to `password` so that the error message gets displayed with the `password` errors and not the `password_confirmation` errors.

How do I make the confirmation error go to the password_confirmation messages?

Comment: just a hint your field should be `password_confirmation`, not `password_confirmed` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-confirmed

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be a direct answer to your question, but will still give desired result.

Look into custom messages for your validation:

```
$messages = [
    'password.confirmed' => 'Your passwords were mismatched',
    'password_confirmation.min' => 'Your password must be at least 4 characters'
];
```

You should be able to get the desired message for any of your fields by utilizing this feature.  Unless I am misunderstanding your issue?